# Django redirect does nothing

Tags: python, django, redirect, request, backend

I am currently try to redirect from one view to another view. However, nothing happens, the token gets printed and that's it.

```
class SocialLoginInvUserAPIView(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

@staticmethod
def post(request):
    print(request.data["token"])
    return redirect("login/")
```

Here is the login url:

```
     url(r'login/$',
      LoginInvUserAPIView.as_view(),
      name='auth_user_login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect("url_name")`

This is how redirect works. Don't give url but give its name. Here,
 you must write:

```
....
return redirect('auth_user_login')
....
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have tried this, but the behaviour is still the same